# Magento-paypal payflow-pro- test credit/debit card works with live mode

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.9, checkout

I have configured Paypal Pay-flow Pro, and live mode is set, but when I use test card details for any card type then it accepts it and successfully checks out.

When I have set Payment Action -Authorization in admin payment settings then it works fine, but not when Payment action will be Sale.
`CC.php` from model file of payment has been overwritten and changes are below :

```
$info->setCcCidEnc($info->encrypt($info->getCcCid()));
```

This line is uncommented in `prepareSave()` function.

What is the exact issue here, I am unable to trace it!

Answer (score 0):

I have got response from paypal support team and they had an issue whereby some of the processed transaction is not appearing in their PayPal account.
their developers fixed it and it's working properly now.
I am posting answer so it may help someone in future.